# Removing duplicate emails in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, duplicate, email-filter

I need to stop the duplicate mail (which is already in my mail box) in Thunderbird or any mail box.

Are there any filters for this?

Comment: Not sure I understand why you are receiving duplicate mail. Are you leaving the option on your mail account to leave a copy on the server? Or is there some other problem that I am not understanding?

Comment: In my case, if I receive an email addressed to me that's also addressed to a mailing list that I'm on I receive two copies.  I'd love to only get one of them....

Comment: Try checking your user profile folder under C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird. Maybe you can see something there. If that's a no go, try upgrading to 3.0.5 AND/OR delete the mails and redownload them.

Comment: @Shiki what would I look for? Also, there is nothing wrong with the e-mails so redownloading them won't fix anything, just loose all the sorting I've done.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need for an extension.

There's a config option in Thunderbird to deal with duplicate messages.  You can delete, move to trash or mark as read if you don't want them appearing in your inbox like normal mail (who would? - I don't know why this isn't set to trash by default).

Ghacks has an article about the topic: [Automatically remove duplicate mails in Thunderbird](https://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/18/automatically-remove-duplicate-mails-in-thunderbird/).

Access the config editor via the “Advanced Options” tab (Tools → Options → Advanced  → Config Editor) and modify the `mail.server.default.dup_action` flag:

- keep = `0`
- delete = `1`
- move to trash = `2`
- mark as read = `3`

It is recommended to experiment with "move to trash" and "mark as read" settings before using the delete option.

Comment: This only has an effect on incoming messages.

Comment: For alreasy in messages, see answers below about the "Remove Duplicate Messages" plugin for Thunderbird?

Comment: **2023 update:** Tools → Settings (scroll to bottom) → Config Editor

Answer (score 6):

How about the ["Remove Duplicate Messages"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/956/) plugin for Thunderbird?

Comment: Last updated in 2014; for the modern (2023→) Thunderbird: https://github.com/eyalroz/removedupes/

Answer (score 5):

I believe there's more development effort behind the "Alternate" version of the "Remove Duplicate Messages" add-on. (Last update March 11, 2011 as of this writing). This is the one I use.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/remove-duplicate-messages-alte/

Note that it refuses to work on "special" folders by default, and you have to enable this option in the settings:  → "Message Comparison" tab → UNcheck "Skip Special Folders (Sent, Drafts etc.)."

I've used this extension on several thousand messages at once (merging mail archives from different mail clients that had used POP to fetch mail) and it hasn't burned me yet. You probably won't want to try it on one of Thunderbird 3's new "unified" folders, as I'm not sure that will turn out too well. Rather, switch to the "All Folders" view and select two individual folders using the context menu option *Set original message folder(s) for next duplicate search*.

*And make backups.*

Comment: P.S.: Forgot to mention that Mutt, naturally, has this capability baked right in. Press the tag-pattern key ("T" by default), then ~= (tilde, equals) as the pattern. The you can operate on the "tagged" messages by prefixing a regular mail command (like 'd' for delete) with ; (semicolon), which means "do whatever I say next on all tagged messages." If you have trouble finding duplicates with threaded conversations, try starting here for a solution: http://linuxjunk.blogspot.com/2008/06/delete-duplicate-emails-in-mutt.html.

Comment: There is more development effort - mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try reading [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Duplicate_messages_received)

It has a couple of suggestions for extensions to delete duplicates and also has some tips on avoiding them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Or try some add-Ons:

Like this,
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/remove-duplicate-messages/

or read this:
http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbird/gr/remove_duplicat.htm

Answer (score 1):

**[Remove Duplicate Messages (Alternate](https://github.com/eyalroz/removedupes/)** for Thunderbird 68-next version:

Answer (score 0):

The kind of de-duping that you're asking for is usually configured on the server.  For example, one can configure Microsoft Exchange to recognize that a particular user is also on a distribution list, and only send one copy:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd577073%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

On the client side, your only real option is to create a filter.  Differentiating the two emails is not immediately obvious to me.  Here's what I would do:

1. In firefox, double click both emails to open them in separate tabs
2. For each email, choose View->Headers->All
3. Compare the headers in both and see if you can determine a differentiating factor
4. If you succeed in (3), then create a custom filter and delete the message based upon the header.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything else, I rather strongly recommend making a backup of all
your emails in Thunderbird.
Make sure Thunderbird is closed.
Then do for example as follows from a `cmd.exe` command line:

```
chDir /D C:\Users\%UserName%\
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a Thunderbird.zip AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\
```

Your backup will now be the zip file `C:\Users\%UserName%\Thunderbird.zip`.

Below I will explain:

1. how to prevent future duplicates in incoming messages, and
2. how to remove already existing duplicates from Thunderbird.

Here we go.

1. In Thunderbird click `Tools` > `Options` and then `Advanced` >
   `Config Editor...`.
   You'll have to promise to be careful.
   In the search box paste **`mail.server.default.dup_action`**.
   Set `Value` to **2**.
   (The default is **0**.)
   Close the *about:config* window.
   From now on you should expect not to receive any new duplicates.
   Any duplicates downloaded should end up in `Trash`.
2. But any duplicate emails you already have in Thunderbird are still there.
   Here is how to fix this.
   In Thunderbird click `Help` > `About Thunderbird` to see what version of
   Thunderbird you are using.
   Close Thunderbird, go to
   https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/removedupes/versions/
   and download the version of the *Remove Duplicate Messages* add-on that is
   compatible with your version.
   To install it, select `Tools` > `Add-ons`.
   At the top of the page, click the gearwheel, select `Install Add-on From File...`
   and locate the downloaded add-on. In the upper right corner click `Restart Now`.

In the Add-ons Manager choose `Extensions` and then `Options` for the add-on.
Uncheck `Skip special folders (Sent, Drafts etc.)` and click OK.
Now select `Tools` > `Remove Duplicates`. Up in the right corner, under
`In every set of dupes, keep:` click `First copy`.
(Or whichever you prefer - it shouldn't matter since they are duplicates, right?)
Click OK.
If you have (had) any duplicates, expect to see
`Moving xxx messages of yyy to Trash` down in the left corner of Thunderbird.

[image: Moving 327 messages of 812 to Trash]

References:
https://www.7-zip.org/
https://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/18/automatically-remove-duplicate-mails-in-thunderbird/
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Duplicate_messages_received

Comment: I should have done this **years** ago! I had duplicates as old as from 2003. For some messages from 2016 I had quadruplets. (!) :-)