# How can I remove duplicate messages from my inbox?

Tags: thunderbird, deduplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing duplicate emails in Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/158996/removing-duplicate-emails-in-thunderbird)

For some reason known only to Thunderbird and Hotmail they decided to re-download all my e-mails, twice. So I now have about 20k duplicate emails scattered around. Are there any tools for going around and scrubbing the dups?

Comment: Well.. mails are sorted on the host usually. If not, try the Remove duplicate posted by jrc03c